# Removing some special characters from array and storing the words in another array

Tags: java, arrays, apache-poi

I have an array that is basically i am reading a .doc file in java through poi jars below is the program now in the array
i got the text

```
String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
```

but upon debugging i found that array consists of these special characters stored they are

```
b\r\n
\r\n
```

now these special characters are also stored inside the array named paragraphs  now i want to create another array name finalParagraphs and want to copy all the words stored in array paragraphs  but in this array no above mentioned special character will be there please advise how to achieve this.

below is the complete program that i have used to read the .doc file

```
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;

public class DocReader {

    public static void readDocFile(String fileName) {

        try {

            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            File fout = new File("H:\\outputfile.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fis);

            WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

            String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();

            System.out.println("Total no of paragraph ---> " + paragraphs.length);
            for (String para : paragraphs) {
                System.out.println(para.toString());
                bw.write(para.toString());
                bw.newLine();

            }
            bw.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {



        readDocFile("H:\\OCT-2015-Generic Printed Pages OCTOBER 2015 Billing.doc");

    }
```

}

folks please advise for this

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
String[] finalParagraphs = new String[paragraphs.length];

for(int i-0;i<paragraphs.length;i++){
  finalParagraphs[i] = paragraphs[i].replaceAll("\b","").replaceAll("\r","").replaceAll("\n","");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i can see now in place of this special characters we have null in array which is not useful as it is occupying unnecessary space in the new array , can you please advise what if we want to completely remove this null spaces also so that final array will contain words

Comment: You get "null" getting stored in the array ?

Answer (score 0):

use a while loop with if statements to match the strings. Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i<array1.length; i++)
 if (array1[i]== "\b" or array1[i]== "\n" or array1[i]== "\r")
    array2[i] == " "
 else
    array2[i] = array1[i]
```

NB - This is all pseudo code. I'm pretty sure you can figure the rest out. Also, the array will have some empty slots where the strings were removed

You can also try using an array list. This one to me is a lot easier, but the concept is the same. Example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
 while (array1[i] != "\b" or array1[i] != "\n" or array1[i] != "\r")
  myArray.add(array1[i])
```

Hope this helps.